# How can I add file names into a listView in android studio

Tags: java, android, file

```
package com.example.snow.unitools;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class savedFile extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_file);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        try {

            String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/storage/emulated/0/Notes/";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath)));

            String line;
            ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lines);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            br.close();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code so far isnt returning anything into the list view. There is files in the /Notes folder. 
 I have also tried..

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "Notes/";
```

But thats not returning anything either. Is there anything I can add into this to get the file names. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using `getExternalFilesDir()` instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`? Those are two different folders. The first is the file location of your app's files on external storage, the second one (the one you are using) is the location of SHARED files across all apps.

Comment: getExternalFilesDir() wont show as an option?

Comment: If you are using an `AppCompatActivity`, then the line `File file = getExternalFilesDir(null);` should return a file.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try this**

```
    private File mFileTemp;

    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        //seperator means "/"
        //this is going for Notes/anynote/filename.jpg 
        mFileTemp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Notes" + File.separator + "anynote" +
                File.separator + ,"filename"+".jpg");
        mFileTemp.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    } else {
        //this is same of up but dont forget you can create any file too and get its path
        //this code will create a file in Notes/Created/newnote.txt
        mFileTemp = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "Notes"+
                File.separator + "Created"+ File.separator + ,"newnote" + ".txt");
        mFileTemp.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
```

> When you wanna use files path

```
mFileTemp.getPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file names in the directory just use that code:

```
File notes = new File(filePath); //getting the notes dir
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

for (File file : notes.listFiles()) { //iterating the files in the dir
    lines.add(file.getName());
}
```